# Spring Boot WebSocket timeout while reading from topic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am using the following Controller to test a simple WebSocket implementation.

```
@RestController
public class SpringController {
    @MessageMapping("/WebSocketAPI")
    @SendTo("/topic/webSocketAPITopic")
    public String webSocketAPI(String message) {
        return "WebSocketAPI response";
    }

    @PostMapping("/WebSocketAPIClient")
    public ResponseEntity<String> webSocketAPIClient(@RequestBody String message) {
        WebSocketAPIClient webSocketApiClient = new WebSocketAPIClient();
        String response = webSocketApiClient.callWebSocketAPI(message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

I want to invoke /WebSocketAPIClient via Postman. And inside it i am making a WebSocket call to /WebSocketAPI via the following client:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompFrameHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WebSocketAPIClient {

    public String callWebSocketAPI(String message) {
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new StandardWebSocketClient());
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        String[] receivedMessage = new String[1];

        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
                session.subscribe("/topic/webSocketAPITopic", new StompFrameHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                        return String.class;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                        receivedMessage[0] = (String) payload;
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
                session.send("/WebSocketAPI", message.getBytes());
            }
        };
        String url = "ws://localhost:8083/WebSocketAPI";
        stompClient.connect(url, sessionHandler);
        try {
            if (latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                return receivedMessage[0];
            } else {
                return "WebSocket API response timeout";
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return "Error occurred during WebSocket communication: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

When i call http://localhost:8083/WebSocketAPIClient with a string input, i am getting WebSocket API response timeout.